# Meaning of "tended, if anything, to undercook food"

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

I am reading the novel by Kate Atkinson, *Life after Life*, and I am unable to understand the following sentence. Could someone help me?

> Before Mrs. Glover's advent there had been a woman called Mary who slouched a great deal and burnt the roasts. Mrs Glover tended, if anything, to undercook food.

Does *the last part* mean that Mrs. Glover always undercooked or never undercooked?

Does *Mrs. Glover Tended* mean she was also a bit slouchy?

Comment: "Tended to undercook" means that she *often* undercooked, or it was *normal* for her to undercook food. It doesn't mean that she *always* did, but that it was more likely to happen than not.

Comment: You used ***undercooked*** in the title and ***undercook*** in the body. I corrected the title based on the Google search.

Answer (score 2):

> Before Mrs. Glover's advent there had been a woman called Mary who slouched a great deal and burnt the roasts. Mrs Glover **tended, if anything, to undercook food.**

***[tend](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tend)*** (verb)

> to be disposed or inclined in action, operation, or effect to do something

[Dictionary.com]

Hence, Mrs. Glover had a tendency to undercook food. Or, she frequently(but not always) undercooked the food. Before Mrs.Glover there was Mary who burnt the roasts, implying , Mary overcooked the food. Perhaps, the author is trying to draw a sharp contrast in the cooking styles of these two women.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to BiscuitBoy's answer, I'll point to the **if anything** part of the sentence, which also implies that Mrs. Glover didn't have anything special about her, other than the fact that she tended to undercook.

It is implied that she didn't really tend to do anything else, meaning she didn't have any other unique character traits that were worth mentioning.

(This is from my understanding of the sentence taken out of context)